# Why do we need time dillation?

Tags: special-relativity

I was wondering why we need time dillation . I close my eyes , I take the assumption that the speed of a light beam is constant for every rest frame.The lifht beam is travelling inside a box . I am inside a box and see the beam go upwards and downwards.Now my dog , Wayne , is inside another box . My dog's box travels at some speed related to my rest frame.The beam of light will have the same speed for both boxes , so I will see my dog's box length to be reduced.Why do I need time dillation for a constant speed of light?

Comment: This doesnt explain why we need time dillation

Comment: Are you asking why time dilation *and*  length contraction are needed?

Comment: We dont need time dillation.We only need length contraction.